# Access post data directly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action in one of my controllers that is going to receive HTTP POST requests from outside of my MVC website.

All these POST requests will have the same parameters and I need to be able to parse the parameters.

How can I access the post data from within the action?

This is potentially a very simple question!

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The POST data from your HTTP Reques can be obtained at `Request.Form`.

Comment: The request isn't coming from a form on a webpage but rather a client application, so I don't think so?

Comment: That doesn't matter. Request.Form is just a wrapper around POST values.

Comment: Here's (probably) why the property is called `Form`: When a web browser sends a POST request from a web form element, the standard Internet media type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".[1] This is a format for encoding key-value pairs with possibly duplicate keys. Each key-value pair is separated by an '&' character, and each key is separated from its value by an '=' character. Keys and values are both escaped by replacing spaces with the '+' character and then using URL encoding on all other characters. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))

Comment: where would the data be if the data was posted as `application/json`?

Comment: I'm also sending post data as "application/json".  I'm not able to view the POST in Request.Form or Request.InputStream.  Does the controller somehow remove the data after it has parsed it?  Is then stored somewhere else?  I am trying to access this data to log the POST data if an error occurs.

This post says that InputStream is disposed after the first time it is accessed, so maybe this is what is happening...

http://omicron-llama.co.uk/2013/02/14/asp-net-modules-reading-inputstream-with-streamreader/

Comment: @TWilly Not sure what the issue in your case might be, but after read the InputStream, you have to set its position to 0 before you can read it again.

Comment: Interesting is the `Request.Form`. Even more interesting is that 27 votes are casted for `You mean ..?`, a half-lined answer without explanation or further reading link.

Comment: Putting [FromForm] before method parameters is a shorthand to bind Post data to them. Then you won't have to access them via Request.Form. The latter may be useful if some values are of types that the datamodel doesn't know how to parse.

Answer (score 39):

```
string data = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Dont forget to add `Request.InputStream.Position=0;` otherwise you might up at an empty string.

Comment: A lot of times in this scenario you'll want to cast the POSTED data to an object.  Since it is usually JSON see http://forums.asp.net/t/1814643.aspx?Convert+JSON+string+to+custom+Object+

Answer (score 19):

Use

```
Request.InputStream
```

This will give you raw access to the body of the HTTP message, which will contain all the POST variables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to access the POST data after I was inside of the MVC controller.  The InputStream was already parsed by the controller so I needed to reset the position of the InputStream to 0 in order to read it again.

This code worked for me...

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
 var result = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Stream req = Request.InputStream;
            req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string json = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            dynamic items = serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
            string id = items["id"];
            string image = items["image"];
```

///you can access paramters by name or index

Answer (score 3):

The web server shouldn't care where the request is coming from. If your client application has a input control called username and it posts to your application it will pick up the same as if your posted if from your own application with an input called username.

One huge caveat is if you have implemented AntiForgeryValidation which will cause a big headache to allow an outside form to post.

Comment: Ok, and I assume it doesn't matter that my client app doesn't have any controls but rather I'm just building up my post params using a StringBuilder?

Comment: If you can post it - it will respond. How you construct the post is of no concern to the web application.