# how to add parameter into HttpContext.Request.Form from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to know how to add parameters into HttpContext.Request.Form via client side so that in the serve side i can get these data
i don't want to use ajax.
I tried the following but with no success:

javascript code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("POST", window.location.host, true);  
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");        
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('key1', 'value1');
    formData.append('key2', 'value2');
    formData.append('skip', '10');
    request.send(formData);
```

the asp.net mvc line of code:

```
var a = HttpContext.Request.Form.GetValues("skip");
```

but a is equal to null.

thank you all

Update:
I want to do something like datatable. In datatbles you can set draw,start, col_order etc. And you can get it with request into the server side. I want to know how can i do something like that.

Comment: Not my wheel house, but should it be: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["skip"]` instead of `HttpContext.Request.Form.GetValues`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885457/access-post-data-directly and https://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/mvc-data-request-controller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to combine data like this - `"key1=value1&key2=value2&skip=10"`.

### View

```
<button type="button" onclick="postData()">Post data</button>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function postData() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "@Url.Action("PostData", "Home")", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("key1=value1&key2=value2&skip=10");
    }
</script>
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {    
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostData(FormCollection collection)
    {
        var key1 = collection["key1"];
        var key2 = collection["key2"];
        var skip = collection["skip"];

        return Json($"key1: {key1}, key2: {key2}, skip: {skip}");
    }
}
```

### Screen Shots

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply, i update my question maybe it will be more clear